# Disappeared question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

My question [Dark matter as invisible part of the Heisenberg’s universal matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365325/2451) (asked 27 October) disappeared with no trace from my SE site together with its upvotes. How can I know what happened?

Answer (score 4):

[Your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365325/dark-matter-as-invisible-part-of-the-heisenberg-s-universal-matter) (10k link only) was deleted by the "[Roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)", which is an algorithm that automatically deletes old questions which have a negative score and meet some other criteria. The details are listed in the help page I just linked. Specifically, the question you're asking about satisfies the following criteria:

> **If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.
>
> This check is run every day across all sites.

In general, when something odd like this happens, it's good if you look around the help center and meta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts (here and on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) to see if you can find an explanation. If you don't, then asking on meta, as you did, is the thing to do.

Comment: Still my question was posted on 27 October and deleted on 18 November, therefore it was not more than 30 days old, and in plus this question received meanwhile two upvotes.

Comment: See my edit for further details.

Answer (score 2):

It should still be available through your profile, but if it has been deleted by the [roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) then it is hidden. To find it, go to the bottom of the `questions` tab of your profile and look for a link to `deleted recent questions`:

> [image]

Questions are normally visible through that link for sixty days; after that, they remain visible if you are the owner (or you have 10k rep) and you have the URL, but they are not linked to anywhere on the site.