# Question deleted without a trace and without notice?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm somewhat annoyed that one of my questions just vanished like it never existed. Shouldn't there at least be some kind of notification in my account left? And why not keep questions that don't have an answer, yet?
The question was related to quantum scars - a relatively recent research topic, which might not be so popular among the Copenhagen orthodoxy... Censorship?

I managed to find it in my bookmarks but nowhere else! Here it is:

[Relation between 't Hooft's deterministic QM and Gutzwillers trace formula?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/336433/)

Comment: What is *"the Copenhagen orthodoxy"*?

Comment: The [Copenhagen interpretation is not popular any more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation#Criticism), I gather.

Comment: There's no censorship here. There's just a specialised question about a subject that few people find interesting, presented in a way that's almost purpose-built, in its lack of context, dry presentation, and barebones structure, to repel any readers that don't already care deeply about both of the subjects you try to link. We operate in an environment ruled by a system tuned to keep the content interesting (which is (mostly) a good thing) and that does include some rough treatment to abandoned questions that bear no signs of readership interest.

Answer (score 8):

[Your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/336433/44126) was asked thirteen months ago. In that time it was viewed by thirty-three people, of whom zero voted postively or negatively. It was automatically deleted by the [roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) after a year as an "abandoned question."

Forgotten questions are deleted without notice by design --- it helps them stay forgotten.

In the future, consider [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Note that your question has now been undeleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

OP's zero score question without answers was [automatically](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) deleted after 1 year. See also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10264/2451) related meta post. It is a deliberate SE design not to inform users of deletions. I manually undeleted OP's question.

Comment: July 28th, 2018: [Community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bot has deleted OP's question again.